# Laravel how to create a custom single item collection

Tags: laravel

in Laravel
you can make this

```
$Member = Member::first();
```

then you can use $member with (->) like *$Member->item_1*

---

how to create a custom object like this

I tried

```
$member = collect([ 
       'item_1' => 'my Value 1',
       'item_2' => 'my Value 2' 
])->first()
```

another try

```
 $member = collect()->first()
 $Member->item_1 = 'my value 1';
 $Member->item_2 = 'my value 2';
```

so, my question is what is the right way to create a custom single collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a plain PHP object or an associative array.

Using Plain PHP Object:

```
$member = new stdClass();
$member->item_1 = 'my Value 1';
$member->item_2 = 'my Value 2';
```

Using Associative Array:

```
$member = [
    'item_1' => 'my Value 1',
    'item_2' => 'my Value 2',
];
```

In both cases, you can access the properties using the arrow operator (->) or array key access:

Using Plain PHP Object:

```
echo $member->item_1; // Output: my Value 1
echo $member->item_2; // Output: my Value 2
```

Using Associative Array:

```
echo $member['item_1']; // Output: my Value 1
echo $member['item_2']; // Output: my Value 2
```

Comment: I've always hated the syntax for `stdClass` objects (`$member = new stdClass(); $member->item_1 = 'my Value 1'; ...`), but you can generate a `stdClass` from an Associative Array using Casting: `$member = (object)['item_1' => 'my Value 1', 'item_2' => 'my Value 2'];`. Slightly more concise syntax 